# Sorting Stanzas in a text file

Tags: sort

I have a file containing many stanzas in the following format. Please note the blank line in between each stanza. I would like to be able to sort this file so that the finished file is each stanza in alphabetical order by index name. Can this be done?

```
[monitor:///..]
disabled = true
index = abc
sourcetype= ...

[monitor:///...]
disabled = true
index = def
sourcetype= ...
```

Comment: Replace single linefeed by some character not used anywhere else, for example a tab. Replace double linefeed by single linefeed. Use `sort` with separator and field specification. Undo replacements after sort.

Answer (score 2):

Using [gawk](/questions/tagged/gawk):

```bsh
gawk -v RS="" '
  match($0, /index = ([^[:space:]]+)/, m) {
    stanzas[m[1]] = $0
  }
  END {
    PROCINFO["sorted_in"] = "@ind_str_asc"
    ORS = "\n\n"
    for (indx in stanzas) print stanzas[indx]
  }
' file
```

Let's add another stanza to the file:

```
[monitor:///..]
disabled = true
index = xyz
sourcetype= ...

[monitor:///..]
disabled = true
index = abc
sourcetype= ...

[monitor:///...]
disabled = true
index = def
sourcetype= ...
```

Then that gawk command results in

```
[monitor:///..]
disabled = true
index = abc
sourcetype= ...

[monitor:///...]
disabled = true
index = def
sourcetype= ...

[monitor:///..]
disabled = true
index = xyz
sourcetype= ...
```

(with a trailing blank line)

Refs:

- builtin [string functions](https://www.gnu.org/software/gawk/manual/html_node/String-Functions.html) for the 3-argument `match()`
- [Using Predefined Array Scanning Orders with gawk](https://www.gnu.org/software/gawk/manual/html_node/Controlling-Scanning.html)

Answer (score 0):

Bash function made with dirkt's comment:

```
function sort_stanzas() {
    declare file_path="$1"
    cat "$file_path" \
        | sed -z \
            -e 's/\n/\t/g' \
            -e 's/\t\t/\n/g' \
        | sort \
        | sed -z \
            -e 's/\n/\t\t/g' \
            -e 's/\t/\n/g'
}
```

Usage: `sort_stanzas <file>`